# Suspendable scripting in Java?

Tags: java, scripting, game-engine

So basically I would ideally like an interpreted language that simply steps through instructions and can suspend execution via method call in that language.

For example,

walkTo(x, y) would be waiting for the operation to finish if it were on its own thread since walking takes longer than the cycle time of one of my game's operations.

So as a result, I'd like the walkTo method to start what it needs to, and then can step through execution calling suspend every time it has done what it needs to for the cycle.

```
function walkTo(x, y) {
    while (curX != x && curY != y) {
        step(whateverDirection);
        suspend();
    }
}
```

or be able to suspend for x amount of cycles like suspend(10)

but I have looked at several resources on accomplishing this and it's hard understanding every little thing about the projects. I was wondering if anyone out there making a game has any idea about this.

Instructions are taken on same thread that calls execute/run/whatever and suspend stops instructions from being read and returns. State is stored, waiting for the next call to execute.

I tried https://github.com/offbynull/coroutines which accomplishes kind of what I want but I want something a little lighter without having to do bytecode instrumentation.

Comment: your goal is just to skip 10 game ticks?

Comment: No, it's to allow operations that take multiple cycles to complete. Like you start an action, it takes a certain amount of ticks to complete, then something else happens and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think an interpreted language for your engine to do might be too hefty of an answer to this problem, you could have a variable that you add to every time the game updates, and when that variable is over a certain threshold, execute code

```
int timer = 0;

public void update() {
    if(timer > 60) {
        doThing();
        timer = 0
    } else {
        timer--;
    }
}
```

If your game updates 60 times a second, then this will run doThing() once every second

Comment: I want it to be in reaction to events mostly. Times are just a simple feature added on top of it.